# Can the cloud functions created in firebase be used in different google developer accounts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, account, google-smart-home

We created google smart home action, and now we have an idea, if we use google developer account A to deploy cloud functions on firebase. Create a google smart home action in google developer account B, then can account A deploy cloud functions on firebase to provide services for the google smart home action project created by account B? If so, what do we need to do? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you will probably want a single Google Cloud Project. In the [user (IAM) settings](https://cloud.google.com/iam), you can add developer B to the project and give them access in a variety of levels (Owner would be the least restrictive, but there are more fine-grained permissions).

Once this is set up, you can have more than one user account able to modify settings and parts of the project.